# two _POST on a single submit button

Tags: php, mysql, post

i have the code of my POST action , but is very long , with two different actions , if the user has the card to buy with money from the vault , and if the user has not the card upgrade the code is something like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['shop'])) {
if (security($_POST['ccard']) == 1) {
$umoney = $urow['bank'] + $urow['money'];
    } else {
$umoney = $urow['money'];
}
mysql_query(set the total upgrade values in another table)
mysql_query(give the user upgrade values in another table)
}
    if (security($_POST['ccard']) == 1) {
    $upuser = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET bank=bank-'$sumtotc' WHERE id='$urow[id]'");
    } else {
$upat2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET money=money-'$sumtotc' WHERE id='$urow[id]'");
}
```

but if i do so , if the user buy something that the value is more than bank , it will be with minus value in bank , i tried with this :

```
if ($urow['bank'] < 0) {
$upmon = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET money=money-'$urow[bank]' WHERE id='$urow[id]'");
$upban = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET bank=0 WHERE id='$urow[id]'");
}
```

Is there another way to make the ccard funtion better? and the value of the bank not to be negative ?

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use IF statement like :

```
$upuser = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` 
SET bank = 
    CASE 
        WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' <= 0  
            THEN 0 
        WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' >= 1 
            THEN bank-'$sumtotc' 
    END 
money = 
    CASE 
        WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' <= 0  
            THEN money-'$urow[bank]'
        WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' >= 1 
            THEN money-'$sumtotc'
    END 

WHERE id='$urow[id]'");
```

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: thank you , the sql is working fine if the value of the upgrade is bigger than the bank value , it will be 0 but the money of the user are the same , what i want to do is bank+money ,if the upg cost 10 000 and the user bank is 6000 and the money of user are 5000 than the user must have 1 000 left after the upgrade.

Comment: thank you , but "money-bank-'$sumtotc'" first the bank - $sumtotc , than money - $sumtotc , because the bank is 0 after the first if statement , it take me the cost from bouth money and bank, if you understand what i want to tell you

Comment: sorry, but i can't understand what you want to say

Comment: I mean if I use the sql so it takes twice the money on an upgrade once the money from the bank and once the money by user..did you understand ?

Comment: thank you abdallah , i made a change with money = like this : `money = CASE WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' <= 0 THEN '$urow[bank]'-'$sumtotc'+'$urow[money]' WHEN bank-'$sumtotc' >= 1 THEN money-'$sumtotc' END WHERE id='$urow[id]'");` but thank you very much because you put me on the right "road" !